# Isotope jquery plugin alternative

Tags: jquery, plugins, filter, jquery-isotope

I am running out of searching, so I decided to ask here.
I want to use something like this:-
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/owAyG/

The Isotope which can using two filters(?)
For example:
1-Group A, Group B, Group C
2-Red, Green, Yellow
The user can click "Group A" and "Green", searching for Green in Group A

But, Isotope required to pay for commercial using.
May I know the free alternative?
I can't find any.
Or somebody can modify through https://razorjack.net/quicksand/?

Thank you.

```
var filterFns = {
  greaterThan50: function() {
    var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
    return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
  },
  even: function() {
    var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
    return parseInt( number, 10 ) % 2 === 0;
  }
};


    var filters = {};


    var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.color-shape',
      filter: function() {

        var isMatched = true;
        var $this = $(this);

        for ( var prop in filters ) {
          var filter = filters[ prop ];
          filter = filterFns[ filter ] || filter;
          if ( filter ) {
            isMatched = isMatched && $(this).is( filter );
          }
          if ( !isMatched ) {
            break;
          }
        }
        return isMatched;
      }
    });



    $('#filters').on( 'click', '.button', function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
      var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
      filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
      $grid.isotope();
    });

    $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
      var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
      $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
        $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
        $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make similar content like the isotope..kindly look at it and let me know if it works for you.All you have to do is to copy paste the content in a text editor and save as html.

hope it will be helpful to you.

```
<pre>




</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>isotope_self</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    *{
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .grid{
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow: hidden;
    }`enter code here`
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

        .element-item
        {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;

            margin:10px 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            float: left;
            position: relative;

        }


        .element-item .name
        {
            left: 10px;
            top: 64px;
            position:absolute;
            text-transform:none;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
        }
        .element-item .symbol
        {
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            font-size: 50px;
            font-weight: bold;

        }
        .element-item .number {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 5px;
}
.element-item .weight {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 80px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.one
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.two
{
    background-color: green;
}
.three
{
    background-color: blue;
}
#btnbox
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: auto;
    height: 120px;

}
#btnbox button{
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 35px;
}

</style>
<body>
<div id="btnbox">
    <button id="btn1">one</button>
    <button id="btn2">two</button>
    <button id="btn3">three</button>
    <button id="btn4">All</button>
    <button id="btn5">number>50</button>
    <button id="btn6">weight>250</button>
</div>
<div class="grid">
                      <div class="element-item one " data-category="one">
                        <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
                        <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
                        <p class="number">20</p>
                        <p class="weight">100</p>
                      </div>


                      <div class="element-item two " data-category="two">
                        <h3 class="name">zinc</h3>
                        <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
                        <p class="number">40</p>
                        <p class="weight">200</p>
                      </div>


                      <div class="element-item two " data-category="two">
                        <h3 class="name">clorine</h3>
                        <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
                        <p class="number">70</p>
                        <p class="weight">300</p>
                      </div>


                      <div class="element-item three " data-category="three">
                        <h3 class="name">iodine</h3>
                        <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
                        <p class="number">80</p>
                        <p class="weight">350</p>
                      </div>


                      <div class="element-item one " data-category="one">
                        <h3 class="name">sulphus</h3>
                        <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
                        <p class="number">60</p>
                        <p class="weight">250</p>
                      </div>


                      <div class="element-item one " data-category="one">
                        <h3 class="name">sodium</h3>
                        <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
                        <p class="number">70</p>
                        <p class="weight">550</p>
                      </div>


                      <div class="element-item two " data-category="two">
                        <h3 class="name">phosphorus</h3>
                        <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
                        <p class="number">20</p>
                        <p class="weight">650</p>
                      </div>


                      <div class="element-item three " data-category="three">
                        <h3 class="name">iodine</h3>
                        <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
                        <p class="number">40</p>
                        <p class="weight">600</p>
                      </div>


                      <div class="element-item two " data-category="two">
                        <h3 class="name">magneese</h3>
                        <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
                        <p class="number">60</p>
                        <p class="weight">500</p>
                      </div>


                      <div class="element-item one " data-category="one">
                        <h3 class="name">br</h3>
                        <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
                        <p class="number">60</p>
                        <p class="weight">650</p>
                      </div>

                      <div class="element-item three " data-category="three">
                        <h3 class="name">gold</h3>
                        <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
                        <p class="number">80</p>
                        <p class="weight">450</p>
                      </div>

                      <div class="element-item three " data-category="three">
                        <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
                        <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
                        <p class="number">70</p>
                        <p class="weight">400</p>
                      </div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#btn1").click(function()
    {
        $(".one").fadeOut(500);

    });

    $("#btn2").click(function()
    {
        $(".two").fadeOut(500);
    });
    $("#btn3").click(function()
    {
        $(".three").fadeOut(500);
    });
    $("#btn4").click(function()
    {
        $(".grid").slideUp();
    });
    /*var filterFns = {
  // show if number is greater than 50
  numberGreaterThan50: function( itemElem ) {
    var number = itemElem.querySelector('.number').textContent;
    return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
  },*/

  $("#btn5").click(function()
  {
                        $(".element-item").each(function()
                        {
                                        var num=parseInt($(this).find(".number").text()) > 50;
                                     if(!num){
                                          // This is .element-item div with number greater Than 50!
                                          // Try to alert its name
                                          //alert($(this).find(".name").html());
                                          //document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=$(this).find(".name").text();
                                          /*$(".element-item").each(function()
                                          {
                                            if(parseInt($(this).find(".number").text()) !=50){
                                                $(this).fadeOut();
                                            }
                                          })*/

                                        $(this).fadeOut();
                                     }
                        });


                      });
  $("#btn6").click(function()
  {
                        $(".element-item").each(function()
                        {
                                        var num1=parseInt($(this).find(".weight").text()) > 200;
                                     if(!num1){


                                        $(this).fadeOut();
                                     }
                        });


                      });
});




</script>
<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>






</pre>
```